# Parallel data to serial with frequencies

Tags: c++, serialization, hex

I am working in the implementation of a parallel to serial data converter, what I have is a program that open many files and write their contents to a single file.
I mean:

ait.ts: `47 D1` (These are hexadecimals so here we have 2 bytes)

nat.ts: `00 00`

pat.ts: `BB FF`

serial: `47 D1 00 00 BB FF`

Now given `ait.ts`, `nat.ts`, `pat.ts` and their respectively frequencies what I need is to make a `serial.ts`, `serial.ts` have to store the data of `ait.ts`, `nat.ts`, `pat.ts` proportional to the frequencies.

Let me explained this with an example:

ait.ts: `47 D1`  f = 2f0

nat.ts: `00 00` f = f0

pat.ts: `BB FF`  f = 3f0

serial: `47 D1 47 D1 00 00 BB FF BB FF BB FF 47 D1 47 D1 00 00 BB FF BB FF BB FF....`

serial have 2 times ait, 1 nat, 3 times pat, 2 times ait, 1 nat, 3 times pat, and so on...

**What I need is to improve my program(the code is at the bottom) to make the second example.
How can I do this?**

This is the program in C++ for the 1st example:

```
int size1, size2, size3;
    ifstream file_1("/home/ait.ts",
            std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!file_1) {
        cerr << "Error abriendo el archivo N° 1.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    ifstream file_2("/home/practicante/Tablas Ts/nit.ts",
            std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!file_2) {
        cerr << "Error abriendo el archivo N° 2.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    ifstream file_3("/home/practicante/Tablas Ts/pat.ts",
            std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!file_3) {
        cerr << "Error abriendo el archivo N° 3.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    ofstream serial_file("/home/practicante/Tablas Ts/serial.ts",
            std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!serial_file) {
        cerr << "Error abriendo el archivo  resultado.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    file_1.seekg(0, ios::end);
    size1 = file_1.tellg();
    file_1.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file_2.seekg(0, ios::end);
    size2 = file_2.tellg();
    file_2.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file_3.seekg(0, ios::end);
    size3 = file_3.tellg();
    file_3.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    printf("%i,%i,%i", size1,size2,size3);

    char* byte = new char[1024];
    while (file_1.read(byte, size1)) {
        serial_file.write(byte, size1);
        file_2.read(byte, size2);
        serial_file.write(byte, size2);
        file_3.read(byte, size3);
        serial_file.write(byte, size3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Does your program not work? Or perhaps you want to extend it so it is able to process many files, not just two?

Comment: @piokuc My program works and do the first example, but what I need is to improve my program to make the second example.